# Spark 2.4.6 + JDBC Reader: When predicate pushdown set to false, is data read in parallel by spark from the engine?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hana

I am trying to extract data from a big table in SAP HANA, which is around 1.5tb in size, and the best way is to run in parallel across nodes and threads. Spark JDBC is the perfect candidate for the task, but in order to actually extract in parallel it requires partition column, lower/upper bound and number of partitions option to be set. To make the operation of the extraction easier, I considered adding an added partition column which would be the row_number() function and use MIN(), MAX() as lower/upper bounds respectively. And then the operations team just would be required to provide the number of partitions to have.

The problem is that HANA runs out of memory and it is very likely that row_number() is too costly on the engine. I can only imagine that over 100 threads run the same query during every fetch to apply the where filters and retrieve the corresponding chunk.

So my question is, if I disable the predicate pushdown option, how does spark behave? is it only read by one executor and then the filters are applied on spark side? Or does it do some magic to split the fetching part from the DB?

What could you suggest for extracting such a big table using the available JDBC reader?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your primary query from Spark, run pre-ingestion query to fetch the size of the Dataset being loaded, i.e. as you have mentioned Min(), Max() etc.

Expecting that the data is uniformly distributed between Min and Max keys, you can partition across executors in Spark by providing Min/Max/Number of Executors.

You don't need(want) to change your primary datasource by adding additional columns to support data ingestion in this case.

Comment: The idea to add a new calculated column such as row_num is to lift the responsability of identifying a suitable partition column for over 700 tables, off the operations team and just require them to say I want this number of connections simultaneously to HANA for this table.

Comment: As long as you have the flexibility to change number of partitions, it could be 10 partitions now, and 20 in the future. Or different use cases may need different partitions